# Offset RefreshControl in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview

**Edit:**
There seems to be a bug in React Native. I have created a bug on GitHub. For everyone coming for a solution: There seems to be none at the moment.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23988

––––

I'm using a translucent header, which is why I gave the `ScrollView` a `paddingTop` to offset the content. When I pull down to refresh, the spinner is still at the top.

I have tried to use `contentInset={{ top: 80 }}` to offset everything, but there is an issue on iOS where it sometimes is not picked up correctly and set to `0`.

Are there any other ways to get the RefreshControl to start lower?

[image]

This is my component:

```
  <Animated.ScrollView
    scrollEventThrottle={1}
    onScroll={Animated.event(
      [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
      { useNativeDriver: true },
    )}
    contentInset={{ top: headerHeight() + 10 }}
  >
```

Comment: Did you resolve this problem?

Comment: @AlexChin No, there is no solution currently. There is an open issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23988

Answer (score 3):

I resolved like this.

```
contentInset={{ top: headerHeight }}
contentOffset={{y: -headerHeight}}
```

I use these props to FlatList.

Comment: This worked for iOS. Had to use `profressViewOffset` on RefreshControl for android. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66691559/9153273

Answer (score 2):

Did you set padding for the `style` or for the `contentContainerStyle`?

Can you provide some code snippet what properties does your ScrollView have and by what is wrapped?

Comment: I have added the code for my ScrollView above. If I set `contentContainerStyle` with padding, there's space I don't want between my child components and the refresh control. As mentioned, contentInset works soooometimes. But sometimes not. It's really weird

Answer (score 2):

```
<RefreshControl
  progressViewOffset={40}
  refreshing={loading}
  onRefresh={onRefresh}
/>
```

progressViewOffset is how you do it, that would offset the loader 40 pixels lower.

Comment: `progressViewOffset` is Android only

Comment: progressViewOffset now supports both android & iOS as of version 0.65 https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.64/refreshcontrol